# Where is the latest MetaMask hello world dapp example?

Tags: metamask, dapp-development, javascript

MetaMask recently added a new permissions check. I'd like a copy-pasteable hello world dapp that includes all best practices and can check the balance of the current user's ERC20 balance for some token.

The web is littered with old examples that either use the wrong version of Web3 or the old MetaMask API.

*No dependencies on NodeJS, NPM, please. I'm seeking a vanilla answer.*

Comment: There's a recent article in metamask blog about it https://medium.com/metamask/eip-1102-preparing-your-dapp-5027b2c9ed76

Comment: Also, I reccomend looking at truffle boxes that act as boilerplate for dapps, they are updated frequently.

Comment: Added a bounty. The answer should live here on Stack Exchange.